# Write a for loop that iterates over to_ten and prints out whether the number is even or odd

Tags: python, for-loop

```
to_ten=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']

for i in range(10):

    if i %2==0:
        i='Number is even'
    else: i='Number is odd'
print(i)
```

Create a list called to_ten containing the numbers from 1-10.Write a for loop that iterates over to_ten and prints out whether the number is even or odd. Please help me understand how to get a statement for each number in the 1-10 list about whether it is even or odd.

Comment: In the code snippet, what is `i` and where do you have the snippet from? It seems to contain code close to the solution. Please ask a precise question or any errors you get in your attempts of solving the problem.

Comment: @DavidWierichs it's clear based on the code what `i` is, but it seems OP is not using his initial list to iterate over and they for some reason are overwriting the value of `i` to a string on the first iteration

Comment: I changed it to this:                                        
to_ten=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for list_element in to_ten:
    if list_element %2==0:
        list_element='Number is even'
    else: list_element='Number is odd'
print(list_element)

Comment: But it still only gives me the first element and not the entire list designated as either even or odd for each number

Answer (score 1):

```
to_ten=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']

for i in to_ten:
    if int(i)%2 == 0:
        print(f'{i} is even')
    else:
        print(f'{i} is odd')
```

Out:

```
1 is odd
2 is even
3 is odd
4 is even
5 is odd
6 is even
7 is odd
8 is even
9 is odd
10 is even
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct,

but you need to indent the print statement in order for the program to print the number in each iteration.

And, range(num) will begin at 0, and the num will not be included in the iteration.

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` is equivalent to `range(1,11)` in python.

```
for i in range(1,11):
    if i % 2 == 0: # If the number divided by two leaves no remainder:
        print(f'{i} is even')
    else:
        print(f'{i} is odd')
```

Output:

```
1 is odd
2 is even
3 is odd
4 is even
5 is odd
6 is even
7 is odd
8 is even
9 is odd
10 is even
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues with your code: first, you substitute a `range()` for `to_ten` so don't actually implement the problem as stated; you make `to_ten` a `list` of `str` instead of a `list` of `int`; your `print(i)` statement is in the wrong order and at the wrong indentation.  The solution of @biplobbiswas does a nice job of addressing all of these minor issues. (+1)

We can simplify the problem by making `to_ten` a `list` of `int`, and have Python generate it for us, to avoid errors.  We can also use the result of `i % 2` as an index rather than test it explicitly with a series of `if` statements:

```
to_ten = [*range(1, 11)]  # a list containing the numbers from 1-10

for number in to_ten:
    print("{} is {}".format(number, ['even', 'odd'][number % 2]))
```

There are numerous ways to go about a problem like this.